# how to forward a message form channel to another user with bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

I'd tried forwarding bot received messages for myself.
my code works for some channels but doesn't work for other channels.

Are the channels different in telegram ?!!

my code:

```
$frmmsgid= $update["message"]["forward_from_message_id"];
$frmcht= $update["message"]["forward_from_chat"]["id"];
forward($myId,$frmcht,urlencode($frmmsgid));
function forward($to, $from, $mes)
{
    $url = $GLOBALS['webSite'] . "/forwardMessage?chat_id=" . $to . "&from_chat_id=" . $from . "&message_id=" . $mes;
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
 }
```

Comment: Can you write the error returned by telegram?

Comment: @91DarioDev
yes: Bad Request: message to forward not found.

Comment: Example (forward from Telegram news channel): 
`https://api.telegram.org/bot*******/forwardMessage?chat_id=****&from_chat_id=-1001005640892&message_id=78`

Comment: The bot is in the channel?

Comment: @91DarioDev  
no! but channel is public. Must be a member?!

Comment: Honestly I don’t know very well limits about telegram channels. It could be a reason. Also remember that bots can’t see messages sent with a date older than about 2 days

Comment: Apparently right! The bot can not forward a message if it is not a member!! and is very bad!
thanks @91DarioDev

Comment: you can use already finished solution - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blank_paper.app.t_forwarder, this the the application for android for autosending telegram messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [91DarioDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372336/91dariodev) mentioned, bots cannot forward message from channels where they aren't admins (bots can't be members of channels, only admins).

Comment: but users can view channel post and forward them, without member of it.